# Ambilight without computer - µC

Tags: microcontroller, signal, video

Firstly, sorry for my english. I'm not very confident with this language but i'll try to give my best for you guys :).

So, now i will talk about my main problem. 
For my school project, i have to create an [ambilight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambilight) system/board (with composite signal or S-video) without computer like the Scimo but i can't buy the Scimo for that.

I made a lot of research about that and i saw this component  http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tvp5150am1.pdf which can make the AD conversion for us and give 27Mhz digital signal if i well understood, right ?

But now i need a µController which can get this signal, get all pixels, make the calculs and then control a strip led.
As a composite video is like a 525*625 resolution, i need for my µController 1Mbyte RAM because we have (525*625= 328 125 pixels and 3 colors per pixels so 328 125 * 3 =  984 375 Bytes needed)

But i also need a µController which can follow the tvp5150am1 at 27Mhz (with digital input).

I watched lot of µControllers but as i am a beginner in µControllers, i don't really know what i need to choose. Currently, i saw this one https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/FRDM-K64F/ which i think can handle my project or the Leopard Board 368.

But i'm not sure for the first one and i think the second one is too expensive for my project...

So can you say me if i can choose these µControllers and the tvp5150am1 component ?
Don't you have a µController which can be like the Scimo and have the video decoder integrated ?

**update:**

Thx for your answers !

Firstly, i forgot to tell it, but i can't use Raspberry Pi too. My teachers said that it's prohibited because it would be easier (not sure for me ^^).

Secondly, I'm totaly agreed with you that i don't need all pixels for my project. So the real main problem isn't the RAM. I haven't though about that I could skip 75% of pixels which i don't need.

But the main problem is always the digital read speed which is needed (27Mhz). Because i'm not sure if, per exemple, an ARM-M3 with 80Mhz clock is sufficient to get digital values at 27Mhz. Isn't it like analog reads ? Which can take several cycles frame to get a value ? Or the digital read frequency on a ARM-M3 80Mhz is 80Mhz ?

Per exemple, do you think this one is okay https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/Atmel/SAM7-H256/ for the project ?

I also though about decrease the fps like Tom L. said, but how can we make that ?

Comment: Before microcontrollers we used discrete logic gates/counters etc.  Internally the microcontroler is just an integrated version of these circuits on a single chip. My advice would be to simplify your problem as much as you can **before** any processing e.g.do you really **need** full pixel resolution?

Comment: It might be overkill, but an easy way to get there is to use a [RaspberryPi with a frame grabber](http://raspberry-at-home.com/video-grabber-for-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: Your English is totally sufficient, but as a suggestion for improvement: If you refer to yourself, "I" is always capitalized in English :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to EE.SE.

I'll first say that apart from a few small misspellings your English looks perfectly understandable to me. Though I may be in the advantage of growing up multi-lingual.

First I wonder whether you need to process all of the pixels?

If you need to make one LED strip on the side light up, get yourself a few JPEG images from the internet, or some show stills from IMDB.com, just some random ones, and see if you can work out with those how few lines/columns of pixels you really need to get a good average.

I'm willing to bet you can easily work with only 1/8th the pixels for just one single channel side-LED.

And even if you need to do 4 edges with 12 different lamps on each edge, you can ignore the middle 75% of the image and probably still only use a simplified set of pixels. That's probably what the Scimo does as well.

That said, I would suggest you look at ARM development boards.

I'm assuming that you are supposed to also work without an operating system on the board, so then I'd suggest looking at Olimex or Brand-Own boards. Companies like Texas Instruments and Atmel make pretty affordable demo-boards using their Cortex-M series controllers and very well designed.

With a Cortex-M series that you choose well (I'd expect M3 or M4) you could get a 80MHz core clock and loads of internal hardware support for quick interfaces that would probably allow you to get all of the data out of such a video chip on time. They will likely not have the RAM you wanted, but if you decide on pixels to keep and to throw away while you read the data and you do it smartly, I'm sure you can do with 1/10th the RAM you thought you needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're kind of overengineering this. Ask yourself the following questions:

- Which pixels am I actually interested in? I would guess it's just the outer two or three rows/columns, you can probably ignore everything in the center.
- Do I really need the full resolution, maybe the video decoder can also output the data in quarter resolution or something even smaller. The number of LEDs you have will basically limit your minimum resolution - a bit more to get smoother data is probably a good idea.
- Framerate: Is 30fps really necessary, could I do with maybe 5 and apply some fading in between?
- Could I get the data using DMA, many microcontrollers nowadays allow DMA transfers, so maybe even the data transfer would be done in hardware